# Web application in Tomcat stops because of "Could not load [org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$3]"

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf

After some minor changes, the WAR cannot be deployed anymore. The following is the main part of catalina.out:

> 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.925 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.37 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.928 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
>   Sep 1 2016 10:01:52 UTC 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.928 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.0.37.0 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.928 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Linux 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.928 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   4.14.14-200.fc26.x86_64 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.928 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.928 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.928 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
>   1.8.0_131-b11 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.929 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation 31-Jan-2018 15:33:01.929 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.37 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.001 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.37 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.001 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.002 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.002 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib64 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.002 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 31-Jan-2018
>   15:33:02.002 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Xms512m 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.004 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Xmx1024m 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.005 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Xss512k 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.005 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.005 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.005 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument: -XX:GCTimeRatio=9 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.005 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.005 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=https://s3.amazonaws.com/......
>   31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.005 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Darchaius.deployment.applicationId= 31-Jan-2018
>   15:33:02.005 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Deureka.environment= 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.005 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Deureka.shouldUseDns=true 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.006 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument: -Deureka.eurekaServer.context=eureka/v2 31-Jan-2018
>   15:33:02.006 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Deureka.eurekaServer.domainName=eureka.us-east-1......
>   31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.006 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Deureka.eurekaServer.port=7001 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.006
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument: -Dnetflix.datacenter=cloud 31-Jan-2018
>   15:33:02.006 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed 31-Jan-2018
>   15:33:02.006 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.084 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat 31-Jan-2018 15:33:02.084
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp . . . SLF4J:
>   Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J:
>   Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. MLog initialization issue: slf4j found no binding or
>   threatened to use its (dangerously silent) NOPLogger. We consider the
>   slf4j library not found. 31 Jan 2018 15:37:56,358 INFO :
>   com.mchange.v2.log.MLog - MLog clients using log4j logging. 31 Jan
>   2018 15:37:57,011 INFO : com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry -
>   Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.1 [built 16-June-2015 00:06:36 -0700; debug?
>   true; trace: 10] 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.383 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.37 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.385 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
>   Sep 1 2016 10:01:52 UTC 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.385 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.0.37.0 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.385 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name: Linux
>   31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.385 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   4.14.14-200.fc26.x86_64 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.385 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.385 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.385 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
>   1.8.0_131-b11 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.385 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.386 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.37 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.386 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.37 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.386 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.386 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.386 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib64 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.387 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 31-Jan-2018
>   15:42:43.387 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Xms512m 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.387 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Xmx1024m 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.387 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Xss512k 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.387 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.387 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.387 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument: -XX:GCTimeRatio=9 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.388 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.388 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=https://s3.amazonaws.com/......
>   31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.388 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Darchaius.deployment.applicationId=batchservicesfig
>   31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.388 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Deureka.environment=stage 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.388 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument: -Deureka.shouldUseDns=true 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.388
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument: -Deureka.eurekaServer.context=eureka/v2
>   31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.389 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Deureka.eurekaServer.domainName=eureka.us-east-1.stage.....
>   31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.389 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Deureka.eurekaServer.port=7001 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.389
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument: -Dnetflix.datacenter=cloud 31-Jan-2018
>   15:42:43.389 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Darchaius.default.configuration.class=com..... 31-Jan-2018
>   15:42:43.389 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -DVAULT_URI=https://vault.devopsapps.us-east-1.stage.....
>   31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.389 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -DVAULT_SECRET_PATH=batchservicesfig 31-Jan-2018
>   15:42:43.389 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed 31-Jan-2018
>   15:42:43.390 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.390 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command
>   line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.390
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp 31-Jan-2018
>   15:42:43.390 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.14 using APR version 1.6.3.
>   31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.390 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true]. 31-Jan-2018 15:42:43.394 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL
>   successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.1.0g-fips 2 Nov 2017) 31-Jan-2018
>   15:42:44.673 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] 31-Jan-2018
>   15:42:44.685 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] 31-Jan-2018 15:42:44.686
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization
>   processed in 2575 ms 31-Jan-2018 15:42:44.955 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service Catalina 31-Jan-2018 15:42:44.956 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.37 31-Jan-2018 15:42:44.991 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web
>   application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/webapps/ROOT.war
>   31-Jan-2018 15:42:56.061 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
>   found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time. SLF4J: Failed to load class
>   "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation
>   (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. 31-Jan-2018 15:43:02.385 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
>   listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
>   appropriate container log file 31-Jan-2018 15:43:02.394 SEVERE
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context []
>   startup failed due to previous errors 31-Jan-2018 15:43:02.423 WARNING
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named
>   [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is
>   very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
>   com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.run(IdleConnectionReaper.java:112)
>   31-Jan-2018 15:43:02.436 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/webapps/ROOT.war has
>   finished in 17,444 ms 31-Jan-2018 15:43:02.439 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] 31-Jan-2018 15:43:02.461 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-apr-8009"] 31-Jan-2018 15:43:02.470 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 17783 ms
>   31-Jan-2018 15:44:01.887 INFO [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading
>   Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
>   already. Could not load [org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$3]. The
>   following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to
>   attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application
>   instance has been stopped already. Could not load
>   [org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$3]. The following stack trace
>   is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate
>   the thread which caused the illegal access. at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1341)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.closeIdle(AbstractConnPool.java:616)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.closeIdleConnections(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:296)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.run(IdleConnectionReaper.java:127)

Please note the same WAR runs well on my local Tomcat 8.0.27 and this problem only occurs on AWS. In addition, without the following code:

```
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
 HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit)client.getConduit();
 HTTPClientPolicy policy = httpConduit.getClient();

 LOGGER.info("CXF client connection timeout: " + 
     policy.getConnectionTimeout());
 LOGGER.info("CXF client async execute timeout: " + 
     policy.getAsyncExecuteTimeout());
 LOGGER.info("CXF client receive timeout: " + 
     policy.getReceiveTimeout());

 policy.setReceiveTimeout(rcvTimeout);
 policy.setConnectionTimeout(connTimeout);
```

it will be fine even on AWS. The above code snippet requires the following dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws', version: '3.2.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-transports-http-hc', version: '3.2.1'
```

Appreciate your help!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

After we moved the same thing to a Spring Boot 1.5 project from Spring 4.3, everything works fine. It seems that Spring Boot does a greater job to handle dependency management.